# Rails Jquery/Ajax change event not executed on Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

UPDATED
Hi all am new to Ajax and jquery please help. I just can't see the problem with this snippet. Basically in my view, when a user selects a course from a dropdown select box, a batch of students who belong to that course should be loaded. The aim is to create an exam for that batch of students.
Here is the code in my create_exam view for the dropdown:

```
<%= select_tag :course_id, 
options_for_select(
Course.find(:all,:select=>"code,id").collect{|c| [c.code,c.id]}),
:data => { :remote => true, :url => url_for(:controller => "exam", 
                                     :action => "update_batch",
                                     :filter =>"course")} %>
```

The update_batch action in my Exam controller is shown below:
     def update_batch
     @batch = Batch.find_all_by_course_id(params[:course_name], :conditions => {  :is_deleted => false, :is_active => true })

```
respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.js
```

end

end

I have created the file 'update_batch.js.erb' with the following javasscript:
    $("#update_batch").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('exam/update_batch')) %>")

My application.js file contains the jquery that hopefully should fire the select box's onchange event:

```
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .

$(function($) {
$("#course_id").change(function() {
$.ajax({
url: '<%=url_for :controller => 'exam',:action => 'update_batch' %>',
type: 'GET',
data: 'course_id=' + this.value,
dataType: 'script'
  })
});
```

});

The dropdown selected box is being populated alright, and when I select a course, the 'update_batch' partial should be rendered. From my terminal output shown below, it is clear the partial is being rendered:
    Processing by ExamController#update_batch as JS
    Parameters: {"filter"=>"course", "course_id"=>"1"}
    Batch Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "batches".* FROM "batches" WHERE "batches"."is_deleted" = 'f' AND "batches"."is_active" = 't' AND "batches"."course_id" IS NULL
  Rendered exam/_update_batch.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered exam/update_batch.js.erb (2.1ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

The problem is that this partial is not being displayed on the webpage. My question is: Is there anything wrong with my jquery code, and is it even necessary at all here? And why is the partial not being displayed on the webpage?
The _update_batch partial is shown below:

```
<% @batch.each do |batch| %>
  <%= link_to batch.course.full_name, batch_exam_groups_path(batch) %> : <%= batch.full_name %> 
<% end %>
```

Am on Rails 3.2.8, and jquery-rails is properly installed. Where could I be going wrong? 
Thanx your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use data-remote with options_for_select, maybe i am wrong. When i need to submit values in a select i do something like:

```
$("#select_id").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "/url_here",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"course_id": id},
    dataType: "choose_the_dataType"
    success: function(data) {
      //do something here 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanx so much for your quick reply. Maybe to put you into context I have edited the question.